# Rerendering MDL drawer menu makes drawer button disappear

Tags: material-design-lite

I'm integrating MDL into a React application.

I've just tried to make a component out of a Fixed Header layout (http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section) and noticed that if I hardcode the layout in the html it works as expected. However if i generate that html at runtime with JS the hamburger icon is missing.

What should I do to fix that problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add an element after dom is already loaded you'll need to 'upgrade' the element. To do so dom-wide, try this snippet

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

[exact issue from the mdlhut](http://mdlhut.com/2015/07/where-is-the-mdl-drawer-icon/)

Comment: The answer is correct and does indeed solve the problem. You can also check this link for additional infos http://quaintous.com/2015/07/09/react-components-with-mdl/   The problem is MDL is advertised as framework-agnostic, but then it does things like setInnerHtml (like in the case of the drawer menu) which clashes with the React lifecycle. Now I see the menu but if I try to rerender I get "Root element has been removed from its original container". Frustrating

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. It seems that in this case need to re-create layout. https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/layout/layout.js#L286